# What does this notation mean? $r_{ij} = < u_i , m_j >, ∀ i, j$

Tags: notation

I'm working through a [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1424269) on Alternating Least Squares and I have come across a notation that I do not understand:

$$r_{ij} = < u_i , m_j >, ∀ i, j$$

Can anyone help by breaking this down step by step for me?

I have searched online for a description of this notation but I can't find an explanation.

As a first step to answering the question, it looks like the meaning of the angle brackets are as follows:

$${\mathcal  {E}}_{n}=\langle {\vec  {e}}_{1},\,\ldots ,\,{\vec  {e}}_{n}\rangle    \qquad    standard \;  basis \; for \; ${\displaystyle \mathbb {R} ^{n}} \mathbb {R} ^{n}$$

*Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Notation*

Comment: Probably dot product applied to matrix component. Look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570887/what-are-the-angle-brackets-in-linear-algebra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\langle{u_i,m_j}\rangle$ is just an inner product on a vector space $\mathcal{V}$, i.e. a function $\langle{u_i,m_j}\rangle: \mathcal{V} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathbb{R}, $ which follows 3 axioms (linearity in $u_i$,symmetric,positive definite). Therefore $r_{i,j}$ is just a scalar value. This is essentially the dot product as @Kristina says but in a more generalised form for vector spaces.